# JPA Inheritance with Multiple Classes

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

This is a question related to inheritance and bi-directional mapping using JPA 2.0 (Eclipselink 2.4.1).

First of all;I am not sure if this is best way to do it, nor if its possible to do it. Please tell me if you think there is a better way to do the same thing, or nearly the same thing.

I am trying to implement a system which maps users to different kind of vehicles (Car and Truck) and all vehicles have at least one photo. I would prefer to have one class only for photos (i.e. VehiclePhoto) since I dont want to do services for all kind of Photos (that would be something like CarPhoto and TruckPhoto).

I have sketch something like a UML diagram over it: [image]

Can you gurus out there help me? Thanks in advance =)

I have tried to implement it as follows:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericPhoto {
    // Abstract class which is common for all kind of photos.
    // Can be omitted in this example, but I will include it
    // anyway.

    protected String description;

    //..    
}

@Entity
@Table(name="VEHICLEPHOTO")
public class VehiclePhoto extends GenericPhoto {

    // This class inherit from GenericPhoto and is a
    // photo class for all vehicles (e.g. Car, Truck, ..)
    // This class must know its dependency, since bi-directional
    // relationship is required.

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;        

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GENERICVEHICLE_ID") 
    private GenericVehicle genericVehicle;

    private boolean coverPhoto;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class GenericVehicle {

    // This class is common for all vehicles. For example,
    // registration number is common for all vehicles since
    // all vehicles needs a registrationnumber.
    //
    // All vehicles also has one or more VehiclePhoto's which shall
    // have a bi-directional relationship to it.
    //
    // All vehicles also has one User which shall be bi-directional
    // relationship.

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "genericVehicle", targetEntity = VehiclePhoto.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    protected Set<VehiclePhoto> photos;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    protected User user;

    protected String registrationNumber;

    //..
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CARS")
public class Car extends GenericVehicle implements Serializable {

    // This class implements a Car and inherit the GenericVehicle
    // class, since it has a registrationnumber, one or more photos
    // and is owned by a user.
    //
    // The only specific for the Car class is the yearModel,
    // gearbox type, etcetera.. 

    private int yearModel;

    //..
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRUCKS")
public class Truck extends GenericVehicle implements Serializable {

    // Same as the Car description but different fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User implements Serializable {

    // {{ userId
    @Id 
    private String userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Car> cars;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Truck> trucks;

    // ...
}

@Test
public void testCreatePhoto() throws Exception {
    User user = new User(TEST_USER_ID, TEST_PASSWORD);
    Car car = dg.getTestCar(); // Get a randomized car
    Truck truck = dg.getTestTruck(); // Get a randomized truck
    VehiclePhoto photoCar = dg.getVehiclePhoto(); // Get a randomized photo for car
    VehiclePhoto photoTruck = dg.getVehiclePhoto(); // Get a randomized photo for truck

    // Add the relationship between photoCar <-> car, photoTruck <-> truck
    photoCar.setGenericVehicle(car);        
    Set<VehiclePhoto> photoCarsSet = new HashSet<VehiclePhoto>();
    photoCarsSet.add(photoCar);
    car.setPhotos(photoCarsSet);

    photoTruck.setGenericVehicle(truck);        
    Set<VehiclePhoto> photoTrucksSet = new HashSet<VehiclePhoto>();
    photoTrucksSet.add(photoTruck);
    truck.setPhotos(photoTrucksSet);

    // Add the relationship between user <-> car, user <-> truck
    car.setUser(user);
    Set<Car> carsSet = new HashSet<Car>();
    carsSet.add(car);       
    user.setCars(carsSet);

    truck.setUser(user);
    Set<Truck> trucksSet = new HashSet<Truck>();
    trucksSet.add(truck);
    user.setTrucks(trucksSet);

    // Persist the objects
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("vehicle-ejb");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();     
    entityManager.persist(user);
    entityManager.flush();  
}
```

The error log:

```
    [EL Finest]: connection: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.509--ServerSession(27042828)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.509--ClientSession(9988705)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--begin transaction
[EL Finest]: query: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.511--ClientSession(9988705)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + #PREALLOC_SIZE WHERE SEQ_NAME = #SEQ_NAME")
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.512--ClientSession(9988705)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [50, SEQ_GEN]
[EL Finest]: query: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.514--ClientSession(9988705)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ValueReadQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = #SEQ_NAME")
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.515--ClientSession(9988705)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [SEQ_GEN]
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.516--ClientSession(9988705)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--local sequencing preallocation for SEQ_GEN: objects: 50 , first: 1, last: 50
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.517--ClientSession(9988705)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--commit transaction
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.584--ServerSession(27042828)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--local sequencing preallocation is copied to preallocation after transaction commit
[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.584--ServerSession(27042828)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.585--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--assign sequence to the object (1 -> info.vehicle.domain.Car@cbda60bc)
[EL Finest]: transaction: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.67--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--persist() operation called on: info.vehicle.domain.VehiclePhoto@d26de99f.
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.671--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--assign sequence to the object (2 -> info.vehicle.domain.VehiclePhoto@d26de99f)
[EL Finest]: transaction: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.691--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--persist() operation called on: info.vehicle.domain.Truck@b295c71e.
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.691--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--assign sequence to the object (3 -> info.vehicle.domain.Truck@b295c71e)
[EL Finest]: transaction: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.719--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--persist() operation called on: info.vehicle.domain.VehiclePhoto@b297753e.
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.72--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--assign sequence to the object (4 -> info.vehicle.domain.VehiclePhoto@b297753e)
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.721--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--begin unit of work flush
[EL Finest]: query: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.726--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query InsertObjectQuery(User [userId=TEST USER #1])
[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.728--ServerSession(27042828)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.729--ClientSession(9988705)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--begin transaction
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.729--ClientSession(9988705)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--INSERT INTO USERS (USERID, PASSWORD) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [TEST USER #1, PASSWORD]
[EL Finest]: query: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.731--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query InsertObjectQuery(info.vehicle.domain.Car@cbda60bc)
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.733--ClientSession(9988705)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--INSERT INTO CARS (ID, ACTIVE, BODY, BODYSLANG, COMMERCIALNAME, CREATEDTIME, DESCRIPTION, GEARBOX, KILOMETRES, PRICE, PULLEY, REGISTRATIONNUMBER, VERIFIED, VTRMAKEMODELNAME, YEARMODEL, USER_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [1, true, _TRUCK_ORDINAL, CAR_STATION_WAGON, sacrifice, 2013-06-15 20:22:36.358, vznxclmndaawethajnahzxgxzzdurifeubrhhqajaiohnjurnrlpcjxfarpbqzqaphgvjjfhzcpozsgfctjnddmhmmncoezhxpqxqdgqgqryysgqsnmryxzlwwqlbkvrksdtrftrgqxnozochtxmznasrhbuxumjzbaqtqujnefvhaeafvcyqcodilpwbnloyzeizcbhekebsdpilfhhrtaxffvnzahnynhnkcwhyvfahrsmywdbcqzsafifwjeielpeyxhbufisfheefybldypnmtpvebnwngmjvjledwpywwbqkvdyjuqzulxdstqukmpctrpxupgpldnobttngdxuvpvjyadoapvszdanspsyoyxefumgbafxdopspbxhocefvsohyutvggoccemreeqdlowwyntgztkbmippjnvqcydkzmwkydgpzdwrxwapgxwnkzeqgmopsfsipqacnkmpvxnkyvsrobppmolfefqbmupgsuwyqefoaiuxjnhxezxnwznyqjjoszmdeuhxomlvoptwmmntjfuegdxvtewosrmpegyjbbdunidfliqyewcicmvbnztuofqovftyljmxixtdoiirrkmxgyycpje, NA, 701421, 904861, PULLEY, the284, false, jebywyypgqorighf, 2009, TEST USER #1]
[EL Finest]: query: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.755--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query InsertObjectQuery(info.vehicle.domain.Truck@b295c71e)
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.756--ClientSession(9988705)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--INSERT INTO TRUCKS (ID, ACTIVE, BODY, BODYSLANG, COMMERCIALNAME, CREATEDTIME, DESCRIPTION, GEARBOX, KILOMETRES, PRICE, PULLEY, REGISTRATIONNUMBER, VERIFIED, VTRMAKEMODELNAME, YEARMODEL, USER_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3, true, _BUS_ORDINAL, BUS_WAGON, axcsjlltvgrgqrvoyldsdykkjop, 2013-06-15 20:22:36.359, qvsiptzlmexveeppkczqcoxcpfmsdwhwamdtwsadohmtgozzxmmvnpwbhpyvzasankutoyfpwjmggsyynehtvhryybltlhdsmqfiueomijkyhewhwnllklkmcwpqnbebbupxmibaeswzgkdkhglmrhaiiehjsivrrjidfoyzvwknaqrdedocopzsluqdvmwgikmkowpobukiwhbgkfypeeetvtzsuiabyxlziqezhrgqlzcqxxhipjsqvtoxukgojhbjubvgbgagonrvbgreqopyrprmdamhssakuxqukevaeuhfopuenednnaambqixriljcwlrqenqcffpirovbzczmxpchcnuhyphtqipcpznhnrzfyofptpcsbesmcssyxaizpfuhxskpiytvpspipdkytulxpxiclqvipjvzpkjrzwqkpzpxtqesclejloawipzrbcagcmhvutkyjwsngenswwc, AUTOMATIC, 190530, 1341699, PULLEY, end208, false, hlklwoixaxg, 1993, TEST USER #1]
[EL Finest]: query: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.762--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query InsertObjectQuery(info.vehicle.domain.VehiclePhoto@d26de99f)
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.762--ClientSession(9988705)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--INSERT INTO VEHICLEPHOTO (ID, COVERPHOTO, DESCRIPTION, FILE, FILENAME, TITLE, UPLOADTIME, GENERICVEHICLE_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [2, false, vycazxirmtesotsfohnqnvrtx, [B@142b4dd, this, ckwbcdyalcdcvjmisozfidsxuutqqepbopvntttxadijmfsklysrzlothvlgwmrfkhkhjypbzhlbxoqo, 2013-06-15 20:22:36.359, 1]
[EL Finest]: query: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.765--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query InsertObjectQuery(info.vehicle.domain.VehiclePhoto@b297753e)
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.765--ClientSession(9988705)--Connection(1579697)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--INSERT INTO VEHICLEPHOTO (ID, COVERPHOTO, DESCRIPTION, FILE, FILENAME, TITLE, UPLOADTIME, GENERICVEHICLE_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [4, false, stemdxpofqjnkycmwjsvygzawpbuzdbinpyweilqhrrchyenawwkjxhxuuafsrewtbwwshcfiytwccofvzpixqebtjxyeqsakqaa, [B@a49e9a, no, oazjleqshliiicpavrvdpxiqyclzvpkgfpzcrtzteoduxmttzbmfdinetwcwzginhokrxnlbaoqzdnhivrdndoscxvtctfvojhiwbdtyzsbaspvnzgefrurcmdamxyhjwcoyvqweuaacs, 2013-06-15 20:22:36.359, 3]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.768--ClientSession(9988705)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT 1
[EL Warning]: 2013-06-15 20:22:36.769--UnitOfWork(7351433)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vehicle_test`.`VEHICLEPHOTO`, CONSTRAINT `FK_VEHICLEPHOTO_GENERICVEHICLE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`GENERICVEHICLE_ID`) REFERENCES `CARS` (`ID`))
Error Code: 1452
Call: INSERT INTO VEHICLEPHOTO (ID, COVERPHOTO, DESCRIPTION, FILE, FILENAME, TITLE, UPLOADTIME, GENERICVEHICLE_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [4, false, stemdxpofqjnkycmwjsvygzawpbuzdbinpyweilqhrrchyenawwkjxhxuuafsrewtbwwshcfiytwccofvzpixqebtjxyeqsakqaa, [B@a49e9a, no, oazjleqshliiicpavrvdpxiqyclzvpkgfpzcrtzteoduxmttzbmfdinetwcwzginhokrxnlbaoqzdnhivrdndoscxvtctfvojhiwbdtyzsbaspvnzgefrurcmdamxyhjwcoyvqweuaacs, 2013-06-15 20:22:36.359, 3]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(info.vehicle.domain.VehiclePhoto@b297753e)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:913)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2875)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:3914)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1565)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:798)
    at info.vehicle.service.jpa.VehiclePhotoRepositoryTest.testCreatePhoto(VehiclePhotoRepositoryTest.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatchman$1.evaluate(TestWatchman.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vehicle_test`.`VEHICLEPHOTO`, CONSTRAINT `FK_VEHICLEPHOTO_GENERICVEHICLE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`GENERICVEHICLE_ID`) REFERENCES `CARS` (`ID`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:842)
    ... 67 more
```

Comment: How did you create the tables?  Looks like there is a constraint on the GENERICVEHICLE_ID field so that it must reference CARS ID field which won't work in this case because the inserted field references a TRUCK entry.  Any reason you are not using joined inheritance for this model?  You might give it a shot and compare if it works better for your model as the queries to find out what type the referenced vehicle are will be more difficult to tune otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Chris, It worked fine with joined inheritance strategy. Did not get it to work with single table.